# When and how has the word широковещательный obtained its negative connotations?

Tags: значения, история-языка

I've stumbled upon this word in Andrey Bely's (Bugaev's) *Символизм как миропонимание (СПб 1994)*. Even in the early 20th century the word was used negatively referring to 'широковещательность метафизики'.

It may also be applied as a radio term, yet its basic meaning, according to dictionaries, is negative and 'fictional' (книжный).

When and how did it become a negative term?

Answer (score 3):

I've only ever heard this word used in the sense of "wide-band" or "broadcasting" (e.g. широковещательный приемник). I doubt a native Russian these days would know the second meaning outside of context, leaving aside its possible negative connotations. I think it should be demoted to "устар." (obsolete).

Answer (score 2):

According to [Толковый словарь Ушакова](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1092150), this term has the second meaning. I could translate it to English as "populist" or "promising" (ironic):

> привлекающий обилием и многообразием обещаний

Comment: This word was mentioned in Kurbsky's letters to Ivan IV in late XVI but I can't trace it farther